# does any one know what is the output of this line code ? $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {pin:p}

Tags: javascript, ajax

does anyone knows what is the output of this line code ?

```
$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {pin:p});
```

I mean I know Its an ajax code that send data through GET, but I want to send the same data manually something like this ".../pin:13" or "http://192.168.4.1:80/pin:13" but doesn't work. 
especially I am confuse about this "{pin:p}" , I don't know the output of that. I appreciate if someone answers.

Comment: `$.get` executes a GET request. GET parameters are what's after the `?` in the URL and are specified by `key=value&key2=value2`, so it'd return whatever `http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=foo` returns where `foo` is the value in the `p` variable. We have no other idea as you haven't given us any other information, and that IP is a private IP on your local network. `{pin:p}` creates a new javascript object where the key `pin` is set to the value of `p`.

Comment: For a GET call, the passed values go through in the 'url'.  So you would need to format the parameters more like ?pin=13.  Why not use a basic ajax call since you're already using jquery using $.ajax() instead of $.GET()?  You can then specify whether the call is a GET or a POST and set the parameters in a more general way.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Also the {pin:p} that is confusing you is a json object with a property named pin with value of p.

Comment: If the server is expecting `/pin:13`, this isn't really a standard format and you'll have to create the URL for it yourself. `$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/pin:" + p);`

Comment: @h2ooooooo - JSON is a way of describing an object.  You can read more on it at http://json.org/  but since you want to argue semantics and troll... from the website itself - "JSON is built on two structures:

A collection of name/value pairs. **In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.**
An ordered list of values. **In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence."** I could go into further detail, but the link provided should be enough and I'm running out of space. :P

Comment: @Nick No - unfortunately you're missing the point. JSON is `{ "foo": "bar" }`. A javascript object can be `{ foo: "bar" }`. An object in javascript is not JSON. It can just be *parsed* by javascript as an object. Javascript objects  are not JSON in the same way PHP arrays are not JSON. They can be *converted* into JSON and *converted* from JSON - but they're not JSON. To tell OP that knows nothing about this that this is JSON is just wrong. It wouldn't parse as JSON and it isn't JSON. There's a reason that the only native way you can get a javascript object as JSON is to use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Nick If you're talking about *the* JSON object in javascript, you're referring to the [base "class"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) that contains methods such as `stringify`. You may also read [JSON: The JavaScript subset that isn't](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Comment: @h2ooooooo - Unfortunately *you* are missing the point here.  The point is, `{ pin: 13 }` refers to an object (think *var*) with a property named pin with the value of 13. `{ pin: 13, foo: bar }` refers to an object (again, think *var*) with two properties - pin (with a value of 13), and foo (with a value of bar).  JSON itself is describing the object.  When all is said and done though, it's a matter of personal perspective - whatever works best for the individual in their interpretation of it.  It's not worth getting into a pissing contest over.

Comment: @Nick By that logic your post is CSV because it'd parse as such. Most HTML (not XHTML) is XML because it'd parse as such. JSON isn't "a javascript object". It's a format. There's no need to throw off OP by a useless statement. It just confuses people new to programming that you start throwing around facts that aren't true. In the future he'll think "ah, JSON!" and start doing `{ foo: "bar" }` and wonder why it doesn't work because you told him it's JSON. Just because the sentence "jeg er mig" contains English letters doesn't make it English.

Answer (score 2):

That would result in a URL request like this:

```
http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=p
```

where you substitute whatever the value of the variable `p` is in this URL.

`{pin:p}` tells jQuery what query string to add to the URL when requesting it where each property/value pair in the object becomes a `prop=value` pair in the URL query string.

If you look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger, you can see exactly what the browser sends out over the wire for any networking request.

---

If what you want to send is this:

http://192.168.4.1:80/pin:13

Then, you will need to construct that URL manually:

```
$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/pin:" + p);
```

You will have to check whether the `:` is allowed in the path portion of the URL or whether it needs to be escaped with a `%3A`.

Answer (score 0):

The `{pin:p}` is the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of your GET request. Your code is equivalent to:

```
$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80?pin=" + p);
```